# Code a mono frequency sound and use it from python

Tags: python, numpy, audio

I'm actually doing a school project about sound and i would like to learn how to use a sound in stereo by using a python (or numpy) program, my experience is to put a microphone somewhere and play two sounds with opposite frequence to "destroy" them. My goal is to have no sound from my microphone, thank you for reading

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no sound playing support in the python standard library. You can try to use for example [this](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.4.4/) library. There are lots of sample programs. One of them even shows ho to play a raw sine signal. Another shows how to visualize microphone input.

To experiment with detructive inteference, I would recommend create two sine signals with an adjustable phase difference and play them as a stereo stream.